# Passing file to a python script as argument using "Shell: send to" through CMD

Tags: python, shell, cmd, sys

I would like to pass a certain file name as a parameter to later be executed by a python script. My vision is to right click a certain file, click send to, and send it to the script through cmd using python path and sys lib.

I have tried to create a .cmd file in which i have stated that when clicked, it would execute the desired script while using %1 as a parameter right after the script. The .cmd file is visible from any "send to" so the problem is that the script is not getting the parameter.

CMD code:

```
@echo off
cls
python C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\FileNameRetriever.py %1
```

python code:

```
import sys
import os.path

path = r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\File.txt'
newfile = open(path, "a+")

file_name = sys.argv[1]
newfile.write(str(file_name))
```

as you can see, the python script, for now, is supposed to get the file name and write it to file (in order for me to check if correct). it does not run any part of the script when i open it from a specific file.

Comment: does your OS use `python` or `py` to recognize `.py` files. If unsure then try running `py` or `python` command in CMD to see which one executes the python interpreter

Comment: That did it, thank you very much!